# "In [some/one] way or another"

Tags: word-choice, difference

The phrase "**one** way or another" appears to be more common than "**some** way or another," but I've seen both of them used online (47m vs 13m results on Google). I wonder if one of them is more correct, common, or idiomatic than the other option. Is there an actual, meaningful distinction between the two?

(I've seen [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-one-some-way-or-another-the-other.1991937/), which seems to discount "some way or another," but doesn't explain why and how it's wrong; plus, the numerous uses of the phrase online make me doubt the conclusions under that post.)

Comment: I think you haven't been looking very carefully! It's quite true that *one way or another* is much more common today. But the version that *used* to be more common was *some way or **other*** - not *some way or **another,*** which was *never* common. There's no difference in meaning, nor is there any significant AmE / BrE usage split. It's just that usages change over time. And there's no "reason" why one of these 3 combinations was never common - that's just how it is. But the versions in your link with *...or **the** other* are just plain ***invalid***, for hopefully obvious reasons.